# Why is sodium bicarbonate added to lower the pH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, ph, buffer

I use salicylaldehyde, chloroacetic acid and sodium hydroxide for the synthesis of *o*-formylphenoxyacetic acid. In the procedure it is written that after the reaction I need to add sodium bicarbonate to lower the pH to $9-10$.

I don't understand why I need to add $\ce{NaHCO3}$, why it is able to lower the $\mathrm{pH}$ and what is the reaction that occur when I add it. Can someone help me?

[image: o-formylphenoxyacetic acid]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poutnik has given an excellent answer to your question:

> Why $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is able to lower the $\mathrm{pH}$ and what is the reaction that occur when I add it?

It is also important that your curiosity shown in the title:

> Why is sodium bicarbonate added to lower the $\mathrm{pH}$?

Since I did not know of your synthetic procedure, I guess this is for your workup procedure partial purification. I also guess chloroacetic acid is your limiting reagent. Thus, looking at your product and excess reagent, you have your intended product (2-formylphenoxyacetic acid as its sodium salt) and starting compound, salicylaldehyde (as sodium phenolate) as minor impurity (it is also possible to have hydroxyacetic acid as its soldium salt in minute amount).

Therefore, it is important to maintain $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution so that you may able to remove some impurity by solvent extraction. If you go lower on $\mathrm{pH}$ (suppose $\mathrm{pH} \lt 2$), then all organic materials would go to the organic layer ($\ce{2-CHO-PhO-CH2CO2H + 2-CHO-PhOH + HO-CH2CO2H}$). However, If you maintain $\mathrm{pH} \approx 7-8$ (suppose you add enough $\ce{NaHCO3}$), then most of 2-CHO-PhOH would go to the organic layer ($\ce{2-CHO-PhO-CH2CO2^-Na+ + HO-CH2CO2^-Na+}$ stay in water layer). To do so:

$$\mathrm{pH}= 8.50 = 10.32 + \log {\left(\frac {[\ce{CO3^2-}]}{[\ce{HCO3-}]} \right)} \ \Rightarrow \  \left(\frac {[\ce{CO3^2-}]}{[\ce{HCO3-}]} \right) \approx 0.015$$

Keep in mind that above calculation is approximation (actual value might deviate from this but not much). Considering you may use just enough $\ce{OH-}$ in the initial reaction and use saturated $\ce{NaHCO3}$ solution to extract, this molar ration would even go lower and  would reach $\mathrm{pH} = 8$ (when molar ratio is about $0.0048$).

$$\left(\frac {[\ce{2-CHO-PhO-}]}{[\ce{2-CHO-PhOH}]} \right) = 10^{8.00-8.34} \approx 0.46$$

Thus, more than $55\%$ of $\ce{2-CHO-PhOH}$ would go to organic phase upon extraction. Hence you may able to remove most of $\ce{2-CHO-PhOH}$ from the mixture with multiple extraction with saturated $\ce{NaHCO3}$ solutions.

**Note:** All of these calculations are approximations, just enough to show the effectiveness of $\mathrm{pH}$ adjustment.

---

**Reference:**

1. Arthur Harry Gerber, “Refractory compositions,”  *European Patent* **1992**, EP0530943A1 (Date of filing: 30/03/1992; Application number: 92302800.5)([PDF](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/fa/7b/40/5d679a76760463/EP0530943A1.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks for your complementary answer. The title question and questions in the body have been worded in unclear way, if the real question was why NaHCO3 or why to lower pH.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear with my wording, I have just started using the forums, next time I will be more precise.
In any case, both answers were very useful and clarified all my doubts.

Answer (score 3):

This answer addresses the original interpretation of the question "Why $\ce{NaHCO3}$ ?“ rather than "Why to lower pH ?“. For the latter, see the Mathew's answer.

The reason of using $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is the reaction:

$$\ce{HCO3- + OH-  <=> CO3^2- + H2O}$$

First, near all hydroxide is converted to carbonate, and then an excess of bicarbonate shifts $\mathrm{pH}$ below 10.

The final mixture forms a carbonate/bicarbonate $\ce{pH}$ buffer with the excess of bicarbonate, because the 2nd dissociation constant of [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid)  $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a2}=10.32$ and

$$\mathrm{pH}=10.32 + \log {\left(\frac {[\ce{CO3^2-}]}{[\ce{HCO3-}]} \right)} $$

Bicarbonates are ideal to shift strongly alkaline $\mathrm{pH}$ to just medium or mildly alkaline $\mathrm{pH}$, without overrunning to neutral or acidic region.